# AVD Manager doesnt respond in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, android-virtual-device

I tried opening AVD manager (tools-> android -> avd manager). But AVD manager is not responding. I tried setting the java_home environment variables,then restarting the IDE.. Still its not working. Any idea on how to resolve this issue?? Iam using IntelliJ IDEA on windows 7.

Comment: if you open it manually, it works?

Comment: how to open it manually?? i opend it via tools-android-avd manager